# FPGA Load Balancing stack

Tags: load-balancing, fpga

I wish to implement a load balancing stack on an FPGA.

Apart from this research : [link text](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=1161527), I haven't found anything available.

Do you know of any LB stacks out there, proprietary or open source?

Cheers,

Louis

Answer (score 0):

Since that requires hardware around the FPGA with multiple Ethernet links, this is going to be hard to find.  However there may be commercial hardware that does this with FPGAs, but that will be fully proprietary.

I would consider doing this in software with DD-WRT or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple ethernet links, you might want to check out Terasic's DE4 or DE2-115 at www.Terasic.com. Used their boards in university. I very much recommend.